# Disable drag&drop of selected text in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, selection, drag-and-drop

When I have some text selected, sometimes I want to select text inside that selection instead (for example because I made a mistake selecting it and want to do it again). Instead, my browsers (Chrome and Firefox) think I want to drag & drop the selected text. I never want that. How can I turn that off?

If possible, I would also like to change what gets selected when you double click or triple click on text, or when you select text with ctrl-shift-arrow keys. I think there are many subtle problems. For example, I think ctrl-shift selection should stop at underscores, just like it does with dashes. Is there any way to just replace the selection logic with my own code?

The drag & drop feature is my main issue, however; I can live with the other thing.

Comment: I don't know how to turn it off, but click once more and you can select freely as you wanted.

Comment: Sure, but I don't want to remember to do that. It happened many times that I accidentally dragged some text somewhere else and didn't even notice until later. I will guarantee you that this will cause me to do many more mistakes before I learn to avoid it.